# Cancel hover when hovering over seperator

Tags: html, css

I want to change the image when I hover on the button, but it may not change when I hover on "separator" in the jsfiddle below.

I don't want to use js

html:

```
<div id="my-thumbnail-link" class="vcenter-parent">
    <img class="vcenter-child">

SEPERATOR

    <a href="#potato" class="vcenter-child">Some Link</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.vcenter-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.vcenter-child {
  align-self: center;
}

#my-thumbnail-link {
}
#my-thumbnail-link img { /* Select all img tag inside div */
  background: url("img") no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}
#my-thumbnail-link:hover img { /* Select all img tag inside div when it is hovered */
  background: url("img1") no-repeat;
}
#my-thumbnail-link a { /* Select all a tag inside div */
  color: gray;
}
#my-thumbnail-link:hover a { /* Select all a tag inside div when it is hovered */
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/srerd881/

Comment: oh thats what you mean... then yeah VVV stop it meeting the conditions you gav

Comment: You'll have to wrap your separator in an html element so that you can specify you don't want this to trigger the image change in your css.

Comment: This is not how you should use image elements. Image elements have a `src` - that is, the image path. Not a background image. A background image can be given to other items. An `img` without `src` is invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `pointer-events` property.

Apply `none` to the wrapper.

Then apply `auto` to the `img` and the `a`.

*Note: According to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) `pointer-events` has good support, however you should note this line:*

> Does not work on links in IE11 and Edge unless display is set to block
>   or inline-block.

You may need to make some adjustments depending on your needs.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwvkvzqm/1/)

```css
.vcenter-parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.vcenter-child {
  align-self: center;
}

#my-thumbnail-link img {
  /* Select all img tag inside div */
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/40") no-repeat;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
}

#my-thumbnail-link:hover img {
  /* Select all img tag inside div when it is hovered */
  background: url("https://unsplash.it/50") no-repeat;
}

#my-thumbnail-link a {
  /* Select all a tag inside div */
  color: gray;
}

#my-thumbnail-link:hover a {
  /* Select all a tag inside div when it is hovered */
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#my-thumbnail-link {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#my-thumbnail-link img,
#my-thumbnail-link a {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-thumbnail-link" class="vcenter-parent">
  <img class="vcenter-child"> SEPERATOR

  <a href="#potato" class="vcenter-child">Some Link</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out by Bram Vanroy in comments, an `img` with no `src` tag will not validate. To use the `background-image` property, an alternative element should be used instead of `img`.

Comment: Note that this is **not** valid HTML, and that using background image instead of a `src` is not done. Rather use a `div` instead of an `img`.